# Do any of the known species besides the Srivani in Star Trek use a phase shift as a cloaking device?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-tos

Please keep in mind "TNG: The Pegasus."

It would appear that this would be a superior cloaking device as a ship could pass through objects.

Comment: Yes. The Federation. Wait. Dammit.

Comment: I know, right? LOL

Answer (score 5):

**The Voth** in VOY: Distant Origin.  They walk around Voyager using their interphasing cloak, taking note of our matriarchal heirarchy and courtship rituals.

> GEGEN: Interphase is stable.
>
> VEER: Curious. I didn't expect the smell.
>
> GEGEN: Well, they are mammals, after all.

Also, **the Romulans** built a prototype like Pegasus in TNG "The Next Phase".  Admittedly it is just a prototype and not "in use."

> LAFORGE: I've never seen anything like this. There's something in here
>   that looks like a molecular phase inverter.
>
> RO: What's that?
>
> LAFORGE: It's supposed to change the structure of matter so it can
>   pass through normal matter and energy. Hang on a second. A few years
>   back, we got intelligence reports that the Klingons were working on
>   trying to combine a phase inverter and a cloaking device. In theory,
>   they believed that a phased ship could hide anywhere, even inside a
>   planet, and that conventional weapons would be useless against it.
>
> RO: How far did they get in their research?
>
> LAFORGE: It never got out of the preliminary stages. There were
>   several accidents. The Romulans might be pursuing the same technology,
>   trying to combine an inverter and a cloaking device. And if this is
>   the prototype
>
> RO: Then that would explain the explosion and the chroniton fields.
>
> LAFORGE: And us.
>
> RO: You mean we're cloaked?
>
> LAFORGE: Not just cloaked, phased.

Also, do subspace cloaks count?  From VOY: "The Think Tank," **Costanza**'s vessel was cloaked in subspace and did not seem to use a static warp bubble so maybe phasing is involved?  Also **Dominion** Houdini mines from DS9: "The Siege of AR-558."

Also there is another example of temporal phase shifting (like the Devidia) in **the Krenim**'s chronoton torpedos.  Though this was not for cloaking so much as for passing through normal shields.

Comment: The Krenim's 'chronoton torpedoes' were out of temporal phase, not spacial phase.

Comment: The Houdini mines were hidden in subspace, not phased

Answer (score 3):

In "TNG: Time's Arrow", the aliens on Devidia apears to be using some kind of phasing technology to render themselves invisible and untouchable.

> **GEORDI:**            *Whatever or whoever's there...             is out of phase with us... But          we're only talking about a          fraction of a second...*
>   **WORF:**          *A fraction of a second would make          them invisible?*
>   **GEORDI:**            *A millisecond, a year... it            wouldn't make any difference...             If what we're reading is accurate,          we're occupying the same space...           but in a different time...*

Comment: Is there evidence for _or_ against the phase differential being the Devidian's natural state? Admittedly, it _would_ mean they'd need technology to unphase to match Earth in the past.

Comment: @T.J.L. - There's no evidence. At my best guess, the invisibility tech is housed in the walking stick (along with the time-traveling tech) but there's no confirmation of it.